# Updated server from 10.04 to 12.04. Still boot from old kernel

Tags: grub2

I have just finished a succesfully upgrade from 10.04.4 to 12.04.1 on my remote server. After reboot, I have verified that it is still booting from the old kernel:

```
$ uname -a
Linux socrates 2.6.32-41-generic-pae #94-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 6 17:08:20 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I have also run update-grub:

```
 $ sudo update-grub
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic-pae
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-41-generic-pae
Found GRUB 2: /boot/grub/core.img
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done
```

But it is still booting from the old one... I have verified that I am still running grub Legacy:

```
   dpkg -l grub* | grep ii
ii  grub                                 0.97-29ubuntu66                     GRand Unified Bootloader (Legacy version)
ii  grub-common                          1.99-21ubuntu3.1                    GRand Unified Bootloader (common files)
```

Comment: Try `sudo aptitude install grub-pc` OR `sudo apt-get install grub-pc` to upgrade from Grub Legacy to Grub 2.

Comment: msPeachy, this is a remote server and I have seen that the procedure to upgrade to grub-pc will ask for a choice at the boot. I can't.

Comment: Please share the content or output of the following commands/files to better help us troubleshoot your problem [(*instructions in this answer*)](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): file(s): `/boot/grub/menu.lst`

Answer (score 1):

You already have installed grub and grub-common

Before you install grub-pc, you could install **boot-repair**, then call it as an application and automatically export its log file to 'http://paste.ubuntu.com' without modifying anything. This log file perhaps detect some errors, you can even post a link to it.

[Cannot overwrite Debian6 grub, with Ubuntu grub2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178513/cannot-overwrite-debian6-grub-with-ubuntu-grub2)

```
Use sudo grub-install /dev/sdX X is the drive letter ex:- a, b You can find it out by doing a sudo fdisk -l

Then do a update-grub2
```

You can use again boot-repair and export another log file without modifying anything

Comment: This is a remote server, without console access. So I can only access it through root/ssh and I cannot risk to brake anything. It is working since 2010 without any problem and I expected a smooth upgrade. Why this problem? I never installed grub2... This is a pure server, no-GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by installing `grub-pc`.
Thanks.